# Non-functioning dropdown bar

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to using javascript and i dont fully understand it yet. I tried making a drop down bar with this html containing of a nav bar with a div that has some anchor tags. The javascript is a function retrieving the anchor tags by class using querySelectorAll. And a let determining whether or not the dropdown menu is open. It will change the style depending on this. If its really bad code please tell me im very new to this.
[image]
[image]

The issue is that when i hover on the dropdown it goes down which is good. But when i leave it it doesnt go back up.

Comment: Don't post images of code, as no one can copy/paste to try your code. Use the `<>` icon on the toolbar to create a runnable code example.

Comment: Share the minimum reproducible code so that we can run and check

Comment: @EagleEye when you are changing the variable dropdown back to true? because your whole logic is under that condition.

Comment: @PaulT. apologies for linking pictures. Im quite new to stackoverflow aswell so i dont know how to do it properly

Comment: @MDMNauman its done in the it =false statement

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow this code structure so that you will not face any issue:

```js
function showDropdown() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").style.display = "block";
    }
    function hideDropdown() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
.dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }       
        .dropdown-btn {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin-top: -1px;
        }
        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" onmouseover="showDropdown()" onmouseout="hideDropdown()">
    <h3 class="dropdown-btn">Hover me</h3>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```